# Can we add <source-file src=""> in the <platform name="windows">

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

In Cordova Appache App,wp8 the following xml is working

```
<platform name="wp8">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="MediaProxy">
            <param name="wp-package" value="MediaProxy"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>
    <source-file src="src/wp/MediaProxy.cs" />
</platform>
```

is it possible to use the same xml with changing platform name to windows

```
<platform name="windows">
    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="MediaProxy">
            <param name="wp-package" value="MediaProxy"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>
    <source-file src="src/wp/MediaProxy.cs" />
</platform>
```

will this code call the c# file

Comment: Do you mean UWP? WPF? It would be useful if you clarify more what do you mean with Windows :). It can be a very open question, if you mean Windows 10 (Universal Windows Platform), perhaps, it would help even to change the tags!

Comment: my requirement is, i want to call a c# code from apache cordova is there any such example, i browsed and found https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/guide/platforms/win8/plugin.html this link where they call a c# code using a windows runtime component. i need a step by step procedure to do it